# Computation of the definite integral $ \int _{\log _e\left(8\right)}^{\infty }\sqrt{\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-3}}\: $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Good evening to everyone! I have the following integral: $$ \int _{\log _e\left(8\right)}^{\infty }\sqrt{\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-3}}\: $$ and I don't know how to study its convergence.
Here's what I tried:
$$ \int _{\log _e\left(8\right)}^{\infty }\sqrt{\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-3}}\,dx\: = \int _{8}^{\infty }\frac {1}{u}\sqrt{\frac{u+1}{u-3}}du\:  $$
And I don't know what to do from here. Thanks for any response.

Comment: @amcalde thanks for telling me I just corrected it

Comment: You can use partial fractions. But I think there is a mistake it stud be $U^3-3u^2$ in the denominator

Comment: Maybe the convergence of the integral is something to consider in first; in particular, I do not see why the change of variables is so important here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to change variables.  Note that $e^x+1\gt e^x-3$, so

$$\sqrt{e^x+1\over e^x-3}\gt1\quad\text{for }x\gt\ln3$$

Thus

$$\int_{\ln8}^\infty\sqrt{e^x+1\over e^x-3}dx\gt\int_{\ln8}^\infty dx$$

and the latter integral clearly diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e^x-3=u$, hence $$e^x\text{d}x=\text{d}u\implies \text{d}x=\frac{\text{d}u}{u+3} \quad \textrm{and} \quad e^x+1=u+4$$ thus your integral becomes $$\int\limits_{5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u+3}\sqrt{\frac{u+4}{u}}\text{d}u$$Now, you can write that $\displaystyle 1\le \sqrt{\frac{u+4}{u}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{u}}$, so $$\int\limits_{5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u+3}\text{d}u\le\int\limits_{5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u+3}\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{u}}\text{d}u$$
so, the integral does not converge.